# What is the difference between CAS default ticket registry and memcache ticket registry behaviours?

Tags: java, memcached, cas

As per the documentation even if we add memcache ticket registry implementation to cache it still asks us to re authenticate.
So what is the use of that?

Thank you,
Ashen

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the default keeps tickets inside the runtime memory while memcache allows your to cluster the CAS environment and share tickets across multiple CAS nodes.

Comment: As per the documentation itself CAS implementation of memcached ticket registry does not support replication and failure of a node will still cause re-authentication. 
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/MemcacheTicketRegistry
Any thoughts @Misagh

Comment: But you said memcache share tickets across multiple nodes. How do you achieve that without replication. What if one node goes down.

Comment: Memcache is a distributed in-memory cache. If you need persistent storage, then there are options available for that too.